# Firebase Web client - signed out while still connected?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a web client sign into Firebase using a custom token a generate on my server, ie

```
const firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);
myAPI.getFirebaseAuthToken().then((token) => { 
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE).then(() =>
     firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).then(() => {
        const myPres = firebase.database.ref('/presences').push({
           id: my_user_id,
           time: new Date().getTime(),
           //               etc                 
        });
        myPres.onDisconnect().remove();
      });
});
```

Is there a way that this client could become un-authenticated without becoming disconnected?

I ask because I have a number of references with `onDisconnect` handlers that seem not to be getting called. These references relate to the user's presence so I have a rule that prevents these references from being written by anyone else. So I'm starting to suspect that the user is getting unauthenticated, then, on disconnect, the writes fail because the user doesn't have access.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I wrote down how authentication state and `onDisconnect` work. If this doesn't help explain your problem, you might want to update your question to show the minimal code that allows us to reproduce the behavior. The code you shared has nothing to do with the Realtime Database, so can't be triggering `onDisconnect` triggers on its own.

Comment: I edited the question. The issue I have is that sometimes, the reference I create here never goes away. The only explanation I can come up with is that the user somehow becomes unauthenticated before the client disconnects, and thus the onDisconnect fails because the client doesn't have write access to that reference any more.

Comment: You could verify that theory by ensuring the clients have permission to delete a reference, even when they're not authenticated. If your theory is correct, the `onDisconnect` should work in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being authenticated is a Firebase Authentication concept. An authentication session lasts from when the user signs in successfully, til when either they sign out, or their session can no longer be extended (if their account gets disabled or deleted, etc).

`onDisconnect` is a Firebase Realtime Database concept. The client communicates with the server using web sockets, and the server uses the state of those sockets to determine whether the client is still connected.

It is definitely possible for the realtime database client to lose its connection to the server, without the user losing their authentication state. The reverse is also possible: the user can be signed out, while the connection to the database is maintained.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question for more detail. Can you elaborate on how the user can get signed out (short of the account being disabled / deleted) while still connected?

Comment: In general the Firebase database doesn't require a user to be authenticated to have access. Your app/security rules might require that, but the database on itself doesn't.